# Python: Downcast dataframe as fast as possible

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, types

Hey I want to downcast the datatypes of a dataframe safely as small and as fast as possible. The dataframe could have any combinations of mixed dtypes in a column, mostly string columns with np.nan or string 'NaN's. Integer columns with nans are converted to pandas 24.2 datatype 'Int8','Int16'... Empty lists and empty dictionaries seems to lead to failures in the converting and downcasting because they are converted to floats(Why??), so i excluded them. My method works, but I can not believe that there is not other simple method to do this, esspecially no faster solution. I think about this now a long time and I need a fast method because I work with dataframes which could be 1000000x150 cells large.

**My method:**

```
def convertAndDowncast(column,downcast=True):
    try:
        column = pd.to_numeric(column, downcast='float',errors='ignore')
        if downcast==True:
            column = pd.to_numeric(column, downcast='integer',errors='ignore')
            if column.dtype == 'int8':
                column = column.astype('Int8',casting='safe')
            elif column.dtype == 'int16':
                column = column.astype('Int16',casting='safe')
            elif column.dtype == 'int32' or column.dtype == 'int64':
                column = column.astype('Int32',casting='safe')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return column
    finally:
        return column


def dtypeCorrection(df,downcast=True):
    if isinstance(df,pd.DataFrame): 
        maskOfNans = df.isnull().values
        array = df.values
        excludedColumns = set(df.columns[(df.applymap(type) == list).any(0)]) | set(df.columns[(df.applymap(type) == dict).any(0)])
        maskOfStringNans = ((((array=='nan')|(array == 'NaN'))|(array =='NaT'))|(array == 'None'))
        combinedMasks = maskOfNans|maskOfStringNans
        array[combinedMasks] = 0
        df[df.columns] = array
        for column in df[set(df)-excludedColumns]:
            df[column] = convertAndDowncast(df[column],downcast=downcast)
        df = df.mask(combinedMasks, np.nan)
    return df
```

**Test:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({0:{'integerColumn':1,'strColumn':'test0','floatColumn':0.1,'strIntegerColumn':'0','strFloatColumn':'0.1',
                                'strObjectColumn':'[1,2,3]','objectColumn':[1,2,3],'strIntegerColumn2':'1','strFloatColumn2':'0.2',
                                'testColumn':{},'testColumn2':[],'testColumn3':[1,2,3]},
                            1:{'integerColumn':np.nan,'strColumn':'test1','floatColumn':np.nan,'strIntegerColumn':'NaN','strFloatColumn':'nan',
                               'strObjectColumn':'NaN','objectColumn':np.nan,'strIntegerColumn2':np.nan,'strFloatColumn2':np.nan,
                               'testColumn':{},'testColumn2':[],'testColumn3':[1,2,3]}},orient='index')

dtypeCorrection(df,downcast=True)
```

**Output of dtypes:**

```
testColumn3           object
integerColumn           Int8
strObjectColumn       object
strFloatColumn2      float32
strIntegerColumn        Int8
strIntegerColumn2       Int8
testColumn2           object
testColumn            object
strFloatColumn       float32
objectColumn          object
floatColumn          float32
strColumn             object
```